# Repeat a sequence and interleave it with an array

Tags: ruby

I have an array like this:

```
array = ['1','a','2','b']
```

I want to make it like this:

```
['x', '1', 'y', 'a', 'x', '2', 'y', 'b']
```

I tried for many hours but has no result. My best attempt was:

```
a = array.each_with_index do |val, index|
  case index
  when index == 0
    a.insert(index, 'x')
  when index.odd?
    a.insert(index, 'x')
  when index.even?
    a.insert(index, 'y')
  end
end
```

Comment: You should try to create a new Array, then add each item from `array` in it with `x` or `y`. Because you may have problem by modifying an Array while you're iterating on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this, using methods from the [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html) module:

```
ary = ['1', 'a', '2', 'b']
xy = ['x', 'y']

ary.zip(xy.cycle)
# => [["1", "x"], ["a", "y"], ["2", "x"], ["b", "y"]]

ary.zip(xy.cycle).flat_map(&:reverse)
# => ["x", "1", "y", "a", "x", "2", "y", "b"]
```

Comment: Very nice - `flat_map` is obviously much better than map -> flatten :)

Comment: @toro2k you make my day! .cycle is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Also any of these ways will work

```
array = ['1','a','2','b']

array.each_slice(2).map {|a| ['x','y'].zip(a)}.flatten.compact
#=>["x", "1", "y", "a", "x", "2", "y", "b"]

(['x','y'] * (array.size / 2.0).ceil).take(array.size).zip(array).flatten
#=>["x", "1", "y", "a", "x", "2", "y", "b"]

array.each_slice(2).flat_map {|a| ['x','y'].zip(a).flatten}.compact
#=>["x", "1", "y", "a", "x", "2", "y", "b"]

['x','y'].cycle(array.size / 2 + array.size % 2).take(array.size).zip(array).flatten
#=>["x", "1", "y", "a", "x", "2", "y", "b"]
```

Comment: @toro2k you are correct. fixed both although you method is still the most idiomatic. I just like having fun with these simple problems to see how many strange solutions there are

Comment: Usually you can find zillions of them! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
array.zip(['x', 'y'].cycle).map(&:reverse).flatten(1) #=> ["x", "1", "y", "a", "x", "2", "y", "b"]
```